# Cross-thread a Chart in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How to Cross-thread a Chart in Vb.Net?
I wrote the following code which works if it runs in Form1, but not in a Module;

```
Module MMModule
Dim MMChart As New Series
Dim MMTimeCounter As Integer
Sub DrawMMCharts()
    Dim timer As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf MMTimer
    timer.Interval = 100
    timer.Enabled = True
    MMChart.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
    Form1.Chart1.Series.Add(MMChart)
End Sub
Private Sub MMTimer()
    MMTimeCounter += 1
    MMChart.Points.AddXY(MMTimeCounter, Math.Sin(25 * MMTimeCounter * (Math.PI / 180)))
End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `Cross Thread` is bad, `Invoking` is good - what do you want? Are you wanting to add Threading to your app?

Comment: Hi FineDay; I just want to create a chart from a Module, the easiest way, because I am beginner.

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. It would better suited to be a Class object that your form can initiate and build based on parameters given.

Comment: Most just add the Chart to a form and then add the data - why is this not the case for you?

Comment: How to do this? The reason I want to do it through a Module is to be able to access it separately and multiple times.

Comment: Can you show me example please. sorry I think I deleted something by mistake.

Comment: In what line do you get an error and what is the error?